# Connect 4, nested for loops not looping

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I am trying to build a connect 4 game in python and I am struggling with the win-checks. I have managed to create a working win-check for the columns. However now I am stuck because my nestled for loops wont loop properly. I am a complete noob so the code is probably real shitty but I just want it to work!

Here is the code:

```
def turnPlan(matrix, rows):
    grid = []
    for r in matrix:
        r2=r[:]
        while len(r2)<rows:
            r2.append(" ")
        grid.append(r2)
    grid=list(zip(*grid))
    grid.reverse()
    return grid


def showPlan(matrix, rows, cols):
    print(end="  ")
    for i in range(cols):
        print(i,end="   ")
    print()
    l = len("┏━━━")
    plan = "┏"+(cols-1)*"━━━┳"+"━━━┓\n"+(rows-1)*("┃"+cols*" - ┃"+"\n"+"┣"+(cols-1)*"━━━╋"+"━━━┫\n")+"┃"+cols*" - ┃"+"\n┗"+(cols-1)*"━━━┻"+"━━━┛"
    matrix = turnPlan(matrix,rows)
    planAsList=list(plan)
    i=0
    while i < rows:
        j=0
        while j < cols:
            z = (2*i+1)*(cols*l+2)+l-2+l*j
            planAsList[z] = matrix[i][j]
            j+=1
        i+=1
    print ("".join(planAsList))
rows=5
cols=6
tur = 0
game_over = False

matrix = tuple([]*rows for x in range(cols))
showPlan(matrix, rows, cols)


def varning(cols):
    while cols <= sel_col:
        if cols <= sel_col:
            print("Välj en giltig kolumn! ")
        break

def full(matrix):
    if len(matrix[sel_col]) == rows:
        print("Kolumnen är full!")


#def vinst_lod(matrix):
    #for c in range(cols):
        #sel_col=matrix[c]
        #amount=len(sel_col)
        #for r in range(amount):
            #try:
                #if sel_col[r:amount]==['X','X','X','X'] or sel_col[r:amount]==["O","O","O","O"]:
                    #return True
            #except IndexError:
                #return
def vinst_vag(matrix, rows, cols):
    obj={}
    for c in range(cols):
        obj[c]=matrix[c]
    for r in range(rows):
        try:
            for x in range(cols):
                print(obj)
                if obj[x][r]=="X" and obj[x+1][r]=="X" and obj[x+2][r]=="X" and obj[x+3][r]=="X":
                    print(obj[x])
                    return True

        except (IndexError, KeyError) as error:
            return








while not game_over:
    if tur == 0:
        sel_col= int(input("Spelare 1 välj kolumn:"))
        varning(cols)
        if cols <= sel_col:
            continue
        full(matrix)
        if len(matrix[sel_col]) == rows:
            continue
        matrix[sel_col].append("X")
        showPlan(matrix,rows, cols)
        if vinst_vag(matrix, rows, cols):
            print("vinst1")
            game_over = True


    else:
        sel_col= int(input("Spelare 2 välj kolumn:"))
        varning(cols)
        if cols <= sel_col:
            continue
        full(matrix)
        if len(matrix[sel_col]) == rows:
            continue
        matrix[sel_col].append("O")
        showPlan(matrix,rows, cols)
        if vinst_vag(matrix, rows, cols):
            print("vinst2")
            game_over = True




    tur += 1
    tur = tur % 2
```

And this is the part I am having trouble with:

```
def vinst_vag(matrix, rows, cols):
    obj={}
    for c in range(cols):
        obj[c]=matrix[c]
    for r in range(rows):
        try:
            for x in range(cols):
                print(obj)
                if obj[x][r]=="X" and obj[x+1][r]=="X" and obj[x+2][r]=="X" and obj[x+3][r]=="X":
                    print(obj[x])
                    return True

        except (IndexError, KeyError) as error:
            return
```

The first loop in the nestled loop works properly, but the second one does not loop. It is always 0. Therefor the win-check only works when there is a value in the first column (column 0).

I would appreciate any help with this, I have looked all over but can not seem to be able to solve this problem.

Comment: As a general tip, when your code doesn't work and you can't tell why, remove any try-excepts that don't print the error message. If you're thinking "well, how do I avoid IndexErrors and KeyErrors then?", try [LBYL instead of EAFP](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pythonengineering/2016/06/29/idiomatic-python-eafp-versus-lbyl/).

Comment: Nitpick: it's "nested loop" not "nestled loop". Although that sounds much more cozy.

Comment: @Johnny Mopp Maybe the code belongs to Nestlé and it's indeed a "nestled" loop